# I have a few versions of Python on ubuntu 16.04 LTS -> how to remove some and not to break down the system

Tags: python, zlib, runit

I've installed a few version of Python on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, please see a screenshot.

[image]

When I tried to delete/uninstall one (not 2.7.12)-> I broke my system, then recovered again.

Is there any way to remove all versions of Python except core 2.7.12 safely / not breaking any dependencies and system?

Plus I have problems with zlib1g-dev now:
[image]

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Well, we *must* ask you how. The way you uninstall software depends entirely upon the the way you originally installed that software.  Your system needs the proper version of Python2 and Python3 to function - uninstalling or breaking those will seriously damage your system.

Comment: agree with the above. also, as it hapens messing with python versions on ubuntu/linux is genrally a bad idea.

Comment: Python 3.6.1 I installed via ./configure -> make -> make install.
Then I reinstall 3.5.2 -> sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.5.2 .
Remove with sudo apt-get remove python3 I guess

Comment: Your second issue is likely unrelated - see for example [Error messages with ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911028/error-messages-with-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Actually my 2nd issue related -> I've got this error when trying to -> sudo apt install zlib1g-dev -> and 2nd issue related to 1st one, I think

Answer (score 0):

When Python 3.6.1 is installed via ./configure -> make -> make install, it should be uninstalled by running `make uninstall` from the same directory.